# Pepperjam | API Location?

Tags: api

I've been searching around and I'm not sure why but I cannot find the API key in my account. Based on all the searches, it points to under Resource -> API keys; but I do not have this option.

Anyone having this problem?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the user did not have enough privileges and therefore not seeing the actual option under "Resources"